# Chrome CSS: adjacent selector with sibling using pseudo element doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm using placeholders for a control that takes user input.

If the placeholder is blank, it displays the placeholder.

I'd like to have the each input is separated by a span.

I'm trying to match the color of the span separators with the input placeholder color.

```css
input {
    width:30px;
    border:none;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
}

/*this doesn't work */
input::-webkit-input-placeholder+span { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="mm"><span>/</span><input style="padding-left:5px" placeholder="yyyy" >
```

This is approach is working for IE using the `:-ms-input-placeholder` selector.

Any thoughts or insights as to why this isn't working in Chrome (or Mozilla) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's working on IE? you should simply use `input + span {}`, why the placeholder in play?

Comment: Why would you need a pseudo selector just to select another element? It does not make sense. Just select the specific input element somehow (using class name, ID etc...) and then the next span sibling.

Comment: `webkit-input-placeholder` is not an element so it can't be a sibling to one

Comment: Actually this is pretty clever if you're trying to have different colors for placeholder and for input text. @TemaniAfif answer works great.

Comment: FWIW - IE and Chrome default placeholder text colors differently - we were looking for uniformity / standardization across the 2 browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown)

```css
input {
  width: 30px;
  border: none;
  color: red;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: gray;
}
input:placeholder-shown+span {
  color: gray;
}

span {
  color: red;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="TEST"><span>/</span><input style="padding-left:5px" placeholder="TEST">
```