# is there a CSS selector for Input field that contains input?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there any css selector for an input form that contains an input?

What i mean is an input field in which a user has typed something (PS: i know of `:valid` and `:invalid` and they're not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: I agree with chris. You can always set a control on blur/change event of an input to check

Comment: There is but it's experimental. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the pseudo class [`:placeholder-shown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) combined with `:not()`. The idea is to change the style of the input when there is no placeholder and when there is no placeholder its means you have some content.

The trick only work if there is a placeholder, so make sure you at least an empty one:

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background:pink;
}


input {
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder=" ">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe anything exists, but there is a specification that is a Working Draft which adds `:blank`. According to the specification, this would allow you to know when an input field is empty. You could easily accomplish the inverse with this too.

But, it's just a working draft. So not available yet. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank).

You can always use Javascript to add/remove a class based on the existence of user input in the meantime.

Comment: That sucks, I'm trying to do something like "input:contains-stuff + label" I'm actually trying to style the label of such input fields

Comment: @Iggs_Grey I am pretty sure you are looking for `:placeholder-shown` ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56564702/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089405/8620333

Comment: @Temani Afif That does the job just the way i want it,  thanks loads.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the input[value] selector, but this will only apply to the dom on page load, so you would need some javascript to handle the input changing (shown below).

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
    
    if (e.target.value !== "")
      e.target.classList.add('hasValue');    
    else
      e.target.classList.remove('hasValue');  
  })
}
```

```css
input[value] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hasValue {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" value="foo" />
```

Comment: Wow, you just did all the work i was gonna do... *copies code * *no regrets * *high 5 *